# How do i check if document.getElementById is null

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How do i go about this?

i tried doing `if(document.getElementById("cart-remove")[0])` but that gives me the error: `ERROR: Execution of script 'New Userscript' failed! Cannot read property '0' of null`

Thanks Alot.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById("cart-remove")`

Comment: what people are trying to say is that `document.getElementById` returns a single element, never an array (or array-like object) - despite the number of non-unique ID's in your HTML ... you're confused with `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName` which return a "collection" - but as you can see, the function names are `getElements` ... plural, whereas getElementById Element is singular

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```js
if(document.getElementById("cart-remove"))
{
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try 

    `if (document.getElementById("cart-remove") === null) {
    .....
    }`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("cart-remove")){}
```

if document.getElementById("cart-remove") is null, then document.getElementById("cart-remove")[0] will give you an error.

You can also do:

```
if(document.getElementById("cart-remove") && document.getElementById("cart-remove")[0]){}
```

Since document.getElementById("cart-remove")[0] will give you an error if document.getElementById("cart-remove") is null, you first check document.getElementById("cart-remove") and then document.getElementById("cart-remove")[0].

Answer (score 0):

null is one of the falsy values in Javascript

```
if(document.getElementById("car-remove"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use equality `===` check inside if condition

```js
if (document.getElementById('x') === null) {
  console.log('It is null')
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
```